# How to stop a form input from registering as invalid when first clicked on?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, css

Say for instance I have some inputs on a form and when filled in correctly, I have the box shadow turn green, but when incorrect it is red. Currently as soon as you click on the box, it is red without any input at all. Is there a way I can prevent it from changing to red or green until something has actually been typed with out using js?

Is there something other than :focus or :valid that could be used here?

**CSS**

```
#contactform input:focus:invalid, #contactform textarea:focus:invalid { 

    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #d45252;
    border-color: #b03535
} 

#contactform input:required:valid, #contactform textarea:required:valid { 
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #5cd053;
    border-color: #28921f;
}
```

edit: Example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/27UZs/

Comment: Can you add your HTML as well? What type of inputs do you have? Do you use patterns or does it validate based on type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want the input to be shown as invalid only if the user has filled something in and then deleted it but not to show as invalid the first time the input gets focus and is empty.

You can use a small JavaScript to do this. It will remove the unfilled class when the user starts typing.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="unfilled" name="name" id="username" placeholder="Rob James" value="" required>
```

**JS**

```
var no1 = document.getElementById("username");

no1.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    if(this.value.length > 0) {
        this.className = "";          
    }
}, false);
```

**CSS**

```
#contactform input:not(.unfilled):focus:invalid { 
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #d45252;
    border-color: #b03535
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/27UZs/1/

Comment: exactly, what I am after. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

if those fields are invalid from beginning then it's going to behave this way. you need to check validity of the fields in javascript by connecting validation function to the `onchange` event, like:

```
btn.onchange = function(){
    //SomeJavaScriptCode
};
```

where for example you can add or remove a class `invalid` as a result of the check